# How to solve .setDisabled is not a function in crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I'm using Dynamics crm 2016, in my code I change fields  disable mode from true to false, when my function change all fields to disable-true it works fine but when I want to change it back to false (unlocked all fields) I get this error:

```
"xrm.Page.getAttribute(...).setDisabled is not a function"
```

I tried different options but all return same result
this is my code:

//WORKS

```
function disableAllFields() {
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, i) {
            if (control && control.getDisabled && !control.getDisabled()) {
                control.setDisabled(true);
            }
        });       
    }
```

//doesn't work - get error

```
function unDisableAllFields() {                      
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, i) {
            if(control && control.getDisabled && !control.getDisabled()) {
                control.setDisabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function unDisableAllFields() {                      
  Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, i) {
    if(control && control.getDisabled) {
      control.setDisabled(false);
    }
  });
}
```

The problem was `!control.getDisabled()`. Got rid of it & now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of attribute and control to understand. In comparison to MVC:

- An attribute is a reference to the model.
- A control is a reference to a control in the view.
- A field has one attribute and can have multiple control. If the name is in 3 sections of the form:

  - Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name')
  - Xrm.Page.getControl('name')
  - Xrm.Page.getControl('name1')
  - Xrm.Page.getControl('name2')

When you call setDisable, it must be done on a control because the attribute has no visual reprensentation.